# Google Chrome 62.0.3202.94 gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn popup_closed_by_user

Tags: google-chrome, google-signin, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

Try sample from documentation
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#example
We could select an account from popup dialog,
but
SignIn don't autorize in Google Chrome version 62.0.3202.94

In my example bilding by this documentation I got the error message with code "popup_closed_by_user"

In Google Chrome version 62.0.3202.94
method
`

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn(options).then(
    function(resp) {
     var auth_code = resp.code;
    },
function(resp) {
     var auth_code = resp.code;
});
```

`

got error response "popup_closed_by_user" and don't autorize user
the same code works fine in oldest chrome version and in other browsers

Answer (score 2):

answer was found
Go to chrome://settings/content/cookies, the "Block third-party cookies" setting.
https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/357